# Shorten code to create DOM fragment using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to create a tree of Element which I'm using as an input to JsTestDriver unit test. Could it be followed using jQuery? I looked into jQuery.parseHTML function, but I need to extract a DOM Element eventually.

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
var root = doc.createElement('DIV');
root.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Web '));
var span1 = doc.createElement('SPAN');
span1.setAttribute("class", HL_CLASS);
span1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('browsers'));
root.appendChild(span1);
root.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(' must '));
var span2 = doc.createElement('SPAN');
span2.setAttribute("class", HL_CLASS);
span2.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('die'));
root.appendChild(span2);
root.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(''));
```

Comment: with createHTMLDocument, it actually depends on the tag you're wanting to create. for example some tags will be moved to <head> and <body> will be inserted. i recommend a documentFragment if you need to support arbitrary HTML tags.

Comment: If it where me, I would make it longer, and do this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ews9uo5e/12/**

Comment: jQuery isn't much better for creating DOM elements unless you resort to HTML slinging, which is unpleasant. I use a function I made based on the [JSONML syntax](http://www.jsonml.org/), which lets you create very complex DOM structures very easily.

Comment: ...this is what your JSONML structure would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/8efc65L7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be shorted dramatically *without* jQuery: After your second line, just assign a string containing HTML to `root.innerHTML`:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
var root = doc.createElement('DIV');
root.innerHTML =
    'Web <span class="' + HL_CLASS +
    '">browsers</span> must <span class="' + HL_CLASS +
    '">die</span>';
```

With jQuery, you can do much the same thing with the `$()` function, which accepts strings containing HTML fragments and creates the DOM elements for them (and stores the top level elements in the jQuery object it returns).

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
var root = $(
    '<div>' +
    'Web <span class="' + HL_CLASS +
    '">browsers</span> must <span class="' + HL_CLASS +
    '">die</span>' +
    '</div>',
    doc)[0];
```

Note that with the jQuery version, I had to pass your custom-built document as the second argument.

Both of those could be made a bit clearer with a bit of simple templating (and there are *many* templating implementations to choose from). Here's a very, very basic example without any templating engine, just to show the benefit:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
var html = 
    '<div>' +
    'Web <span class="{HL_CLASS}">browsers</span> ' +
    'must <span class="{HL_CLASS}">die</span>' +
    '</div>';
var root = $(html.replace(/\{HL_CLASS\}/g, HL_CLASS), doc)[0];
```

Ideally, though, you'd load that template dynamically from a file where you can edit it properly (using a build tool to embed it for production), rather than string literals.

Comment: But how do I get the top level element from the jQuery object?

Comment: @prasopes: See the jQuery documentation. jQuery objects are just wrappers for sets of elements, you can access the elements within the set using indexes: `var x = $("<div><span>hi there</span></div>");` results in a set containing the `div` (which of course has a child element with text in it). `x[0]` gives you the `HTMLDivElement` instance.

Comment: The question is why would you, there's no point in writing shorter code unless it's also more efficient or have other benefits, which using strings doesn't. Stick with what you've got.

Comment: @adeneo: Using HTML with templating, ideally loaded from a file, is *dramatically* clearer and easier to maintain. (I can't say `innerHTML` is dramatically faster anymore; that was six years ago, browsers have sped up their DOM calls. :-) )

Comment: I think writting it this way is much more uglier, even being the best jQuery implementation of it

Comment: @SantiagoRebella: With templating, you're authoring HTML and rendering it. Doesn't get any simpler -- or better supported by tools -- than that.

Comment: i do like templates, underscore and angular mostly, just dont like to write a bunch of html as string

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

```
var $dock = $('body'), $root = $('<div/>', { 'id' : 'adOverlay' }), 
    $container = $('<div/>', { 'id' : 'adContainer' }).appendTo($root),  
    $exterior = $('<div/>', { 'id' : 'adOutdoor' }).appendTo($container), 
    $interior = $('<div/>', { 'id' : 'adInterior' }).appendTo($container), 
    $retrovisor = $('<div/>', { 'id' : 'adRetrovisor' }).appendTo($interior), 
    $retrovisorInner = $('<div/>').appendTo($retrovisor), 
    $close = $('<div/>', { 'id' : 'adOverlayClose' }).append('<div>&times;</div>').appendTo($root);
    $root.appendTo($dock);
```

EDIT

I mean I think is a clean way to do it, but you could also use `.html('<div>you html here</div>');`

Comment: This is a straight translation, and as such, it's probably the *worst* jQuery implementation of this.

Comment: hi @meagar could you please explain more

Comment: See the other answer. It's a tiny fraction of the amount of code to just write out the HTML and wrap it in `$()`.

Comment: depends on whats the use for, i think this is quite clean solution

Comment: with this you can manipulate all your elements as objects and when you are ready just append it

Comment: If manipulating individual elements were actually a requirement, then it might be relevant.

Comment: And even if it were, you can readily do that once you you've build the set in the first place. Also note that this ignores the OP's use of a separate document entirely.

Comment: I thought the relevance was in how to create DOM fragments using jQuery